# After updating the app, user reports crash on iPad 1 running iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, ios5

There is no crashalytics crash report that I get. And the user says that the app just hangs on the opening screen.

And this started happening only a few days ago. Would anyone know why this happens? And is there any reason why this started happening now?

When I run the app on my simulator with iOS 5.1 it works just fine.

Comment: Does it use CoreData and if so has the schema changed?

Comment: have you run it on an iPad1 yourself (not simulator)?

Comment: @D80Buckeye I don't have iPad1 :)

Comment: @logixologist no, it isn't using core data.

Comment: is it a free app in the app store?

Comment: @D80Buckeye no, it is paid, but I can give you a promo code if you can take a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I emailed you the crash logs & console logs. The immediate meat of it looks like you have a problem with ACFacebookAppIDKey...

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _ACFacebookAppIdKey
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/<removed by D80buckeye>/BusinessPlan.app/BusinessPlan
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
 in /var/mobile/Applications/<removed by D80buckeye>/BusinessPlan.app/BusinessPlan
  Dyld Version: 199.6
```

EDIT:
With a little more research I think I found your problem. ACFacebookAppIDKey is only available in iOS6 and above. From [ACAccountstore Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/ACFacebookAppIdKey)

```
ACFacebookAppIdKey
The Facebook App ID, as it appears on the Facebook website.
Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
Declared in ACAccountStore.h.
```

Comment: NP - let me know when you need it tested again :)

Comment: by the way, that ACFacebookAppIdKey it was complaining about. Would you have thoughts on where it might be? I looked in the pList and there I had only FacebookDisplayName and FacebookDisplayName but I don't see where is the reference to ACFacebookAppIdKey that I need to get rid of.

Answer (score 2):

Mark Social.framework, Accounts.framework as 'optional' in XCODE, NOT required, in Targets/Build Phases/Link Binary with Libraries.

Comment: I just totally deleted the Social.Framework. Is that bad? What would have been the right way to go about deleting all the fb references? I don't need those libraries anyway.

Comment: I did just make the Accounts.framework optional. But the Social.framework is gone now.

Comment: It's not bad to delete any of the frameworks that I mentioned if you don't need them for FB/Twitter access. I know that some developers use FB's own libraries for devices running 5.1.1 and the twitter framework for those same devices. It's your call on how you wish to proceed.

Comment: I don't mind ripping it out entirely. I am just worried I might forget something. Where is that _ACFacebookAppIdKey variable located? And would you know what is causing the crash? Is it the "required" field? Or a reference elsewhere? Thank you!!

Comment: I had the same problem when using the frameworks. I didn't experience any crash using the 5.1.1 simulator and I foolishly thought that simulation was good enough. Once I started receiving complaints from my customers, I tested my app on an iPad 1 and was able to reproduce the crashes perfectly. In my case, it was definitely the frameworks. If you remove them entirely, then be certain that you remove (or comment out) the code that calls FB or Twitter.

Comment: by the way, do you know if I left AdSupport.framework, libsqlite3.dylib, Security.framework as required, would it still crash the iOS 5.1 devices?

Comment: Perhaps this link can help you: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html

Comment: that list doesn't mention libsqlite3.dylib but I am safe leaving that in, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the sqlite library. That shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: BUt it's REALLY important that you test your app on real devices...then you will know for certain in every case.